# How to create a 64-bit apk file to install on Android 5.0

Tags: android, apk, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to create a 64 bit apk file to install on the Android 5.0 (64 bit) device. I want to run my test app on that device, I am using Eclipse Juno, how do I do it?

Comment: hmmm are you using native code ... if no please tell me where did hear that you need different apk for different ABI?

Comment: yes I am using native code, I read in some document that Android 5.0 device runs both 32 bit apps and 64 bit apps, I was wondering how to run my test app in 64 bit.

Comment: set APP_ABI to x64(not ALL) in Application.mk file ... it will produce only x64 version ... apk is in fact zip file ... check if it continas "libs/x64/libyourlib.so" file after this ...

Comment: where is Application.mk file, I cant find it. how to create if I am not using native code ?

Comment: FWIW, it appears that ARM 64 devices can run 32/64 bits exe, however Intel 64 devices cannot run 32 bits exe, it reports and ELF error! :(